# Estimate warming caused by the current sea ice anomaly in Antarctica

Tags: climate-change, antarctica

I’ve read about the Ice Albedo Feedback effect on global warming. Antarctica has had a large sea ice anomaly from late 2021 until now. What is the average change in energy flux over the period 21 June 2022 to 20 June 2023 (compared to the 2011-2020 average) because of this anomaly?

Comment: My rough estimate is based on anomaly of -1.5*10^12 m2, average insolation at -70 degrees latitude of 200 W/m2, difference between ice albedo and ocean albedo of 0.5. This gives 1.5*10^14 W, so dividing by surface area of Earth (5.1*10^14 m2) this is 0.29 W/m2. I don’t know enough about this area to know which assumptions and simplifications I’ve made here are wrong.